# How do I copy a stack in Java?

Tags: java, string, copy, stack

I have a stack A and I want to create a stack B that is identical to stack A. I don't want stack B to simply be a pointer to A -- I actually want to create a new stack B that contains the same elements as stack A in the same order as stack A. Stack A is a stack of strings.

Thanks!

Comment: `Stack<String> b = (Stack<String>) a.clone();`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just use the clone() -method of the Stack-class (it implements Cloneable).

Here's a simple test-case with JUnit:

```
@Test   
public void test()
{
    Stack<Integer> intStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)        
    {
        intStack.push(i);
    }

    Stack<Integer> copiedStack = (Stack<Integer>)intStack.clone();

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)            
    {
        Assert.assertEquals(intStack.pop(), copiedStack.pop());
    }
}
```

Edit:

> tmsimont: This creates a "unchecked or unsafe operations" warning for me. Any
>   way to do this without generating this problem?

I at first responded that the warning would be unavoidable, but actually it is avoidable using `<?>` (wildcard) -typing:

```
@Test
public void test()
{
    Stack<Integer> intStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        intStack.push(i);
    }

    //No warning
    Stack<?> copiedStack = (Stack<?>)intStack.clone();

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Integer value = (Integer)copiedStack.pop(); //Won't cause a warning, no matter to which type you cast (String, Float...), but will throw ClassCastException at runtime if the type is wrong
        Assert.assertEquals(intStack.pop(), value);
    }
}
```

Basically I'd say you're still doing an unchecked cast from `?` (unknown type) to `Integer`, but there's no warning. Personally, I'd still prefer to cast directly into `Stack<Integer>` and suppress the warning with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Comment: This creates a "unchecked or unsafe operations" warning for me. Any way to do this without generating this problem?

Comment: @tmsimont: disregard my previous comment and see the edited answer, it is possible to prevent the warning without using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Comment: Thank you. This is madness.

Answer (score 22):

`Stack` extends `Vector`, so you can just new up a new `Stack` and use `.addAll(...)` to copy the items:

```
Stack<Type> newStack = new Stack<Type>();
newStack.addAll(oldStack);
```

Comment: This won't copy the member items.  Both stacks will point at the same Strings.

Comment: Strings are immutable, so making a copy of a string doesn't help any.

Answer (score 4):

The [Stack](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class is a sub-class of [AbstractList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html).

Simply treat it like an AbstractList, iterate through the elements in the stack using the `get(int index)` method, from 0 to the length of your list/stack, and add the elements to the new stack.

This won't copy the elements - it will add the elements to the new stack. If you need to copy the elements as well, you'll need to go another level deep and create copies of the elements, and add those to the new stack.

You can do [full (or "deep") copies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy), by using the `clone` method, but note that the object must implement the [Clonable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) interface in order to get [deep copies of objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [clone](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#clone%28%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
     * Copy constructor for the Stack class
     * @param original the Stack to copy
     * @postcondition a new Stack object which is
     * an identical, but distinct, copy of original
     */
    public Stack(Stack<T> original) {
        if (original.length == 0)
        {
            length = 0;
            top = null;
        } else
        {
            Node temp = original.top;
            while (temp != null)
            {
                push(temp.data); // inserts into this
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            temp = top;
            temp = temp.next;
            top.next = null;
            while (temp != null){
                push(temp.data); // inserts into this
                temp = temp.next;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919836/how-do-i-copy-a-stack-in-java/54374572#54374572) you just posted. Stack Overflow does not tolerate duplicate answers. Please delete one of the answers you posted.

Answer (score -1):

```java
 /**
 * Copy constructor for the Stack class
 * @param original the Stack to copy
 * @postcondition a new Stack object which is
 * an identical, but distinct, copy of original
 */
public Stack(Stack<T> original) {
    if (original.length == 0)
    {
        length = 0;
        top = null;
    } else
    {
        Node temp = original.top;
        while (temp != null)
        {
            push(temp.data); // inserts into this
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        temp = top;
        temp = temp.next;
        top.next = null;
        while (temp != null){
            push(temp.data); // inserts into this
            temp = temp.next;
        }

    }
}
```